# Invalid Hook Call error after updating react vesion from 16.13.1 .to 17.0.1

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting the following error in my react-web application.

*Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.*.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { Button, Dropdown } from 'tabler-react';
import regeneratorRuntime from 'regenerator-runtime';

const LanguageSelector = () => {
  const {t, i18n} = useTranslation();

  const clicked = (event) => {
    i18n.changeLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  const clickedEn = () => {
    i18n.changeLanguage("en");
  };

  const clickedTr = () => {
    i18n.changeLanguage("tr");
  };

  return (
    <Button.List align={"right"}>
      <Dropdown
        outline
        type="button"
        size="sm"
        toggle={false}
        color="primary"
        arrow
        icon="globe"
        triggerContent={t('selectLanguage')}
        itemsObject={[
          {
            value: "English",
            onClick: clickedEn
          },
          {isDivider: true},
          {
            value: "Türkçe",
            onClick: clickedTr
          },
        ]}
      />
    </Button.List>
  );
};

export default LanguageSelector;
```

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "smt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "module": "dist/index.es.js",
  "jsnext:main": "dist/index.es.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8",
    "npm": ">=5"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.0 || ^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.0.0 || ^16.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.8",
    "konva": "^7.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.1",
    "react-konva": "^17.0.0-0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the current `react-dom` version right now?

Comment: I edited the question to also include the package.json. So according to this the react-dom is 16.12.0.

Comment: I can't see the updated version in your `package.json`. Just check if both `react` and `react-dom` is updated. If those are ok it seems that the problem is not happening in this component.